# Magento get weigth of configurable product

Tags: php, magento

good afternoon,
How can I recover the value in phtml from the weight of the product? this product is configurable, so it has variations, it needed to recover the weight of the variation

i use this for Default products:

```
$_product->getWeight()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that the product model is loaded.

You need to load the model of the configurable in order to access its child products (variations).

Here is an example

```
<?php $configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // selecting all attributes?>

<?php foreach($simpleCollection as $simple): ?>
    <?php echo $simple->getWeight(); ?>
     <?php // or?>
    <?php echo $simple->getAttributeText('weight'); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Omg! nice, how i call other weight if i select a color or size? you know that?

Comment: You mean getting other attributes of the child product?
<?php echo $simple->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
You can do it like that if thats what you mean

If my post is answering your question mark it please :).